# JavaScript operation with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have group of check boxes and i need when checkboxes selected or deselected then local variable 'address' containing values of checkboxen but in my format.
Sample:

```
http://localhost/?param=1&cb[gr1]=vl1-vl3&cb[gr2]=vl1&cb[gr3]=vl1-vl2-vl3
```

If i select
Group 1 - vl1 and vl3
Group 2 - vl1
Group 3 - vl1 and vl2 and vl3

```
http://localhost/?param=1
&cb[gr1]=vl1-vl3
&cb[gr2]=vl1
&cb[gr3]=vl1-vl2-vl3
```

How to make such a miracle in Java script?

And this source of html

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group 1</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl1"/>value 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl2"/>value 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl3"/>value 3<br/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group 2</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr2[]" value="vl1"/>value 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr2[]" value="vl2"/>value 2<br/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group 3</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl1"/>value 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl2"/>value 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl3"/>value 3<br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vqr1ksy/

Comment: Please move your code from the fiddle to this site itself.

Comment: I hope you are aware that POST request actually sends data in body, not in query parameters. If yes and you know what you're doing, so you have to handle data sending process yourself: intercept form' submit, construct body and query, send data. In the second step (construct query) take all the selected checkboxes arranged in one fieldset and join their values, that's it.

Comment: No no, POST not needed. I want set local JS string variable with parameters in my string format

Comment: My solution but with problem https://jsfiddle.net/3vqr1ksy/3/

Answer (score 2):

To get these strings on the clientside, do this:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('fieldset')].forEach(function(fs) {
  fs.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    let checkedValues = [...this.querySelectorAll(':checked')].map(cb => cb.value).join('-')
    window[this.dataset.group].textContent = checkedValues
  })
})
```

```css
fieldset {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
}
```

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <fieldset data-group="g1">
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl1" />value 1</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl2" />value 2</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr1[]" value="vl3" />value 3</label><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset data-group="g2">
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr2[]" value="vl1" />value 1</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr2[]" value="vl2" />value 2</label><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset data-group="g3">
    <legend>Group 3</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl1" />value 1</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl2" />value 2</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="gr3[]" value="vl3" />value 3</label><br/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div>Group 1: <span id="g1"></span></div>
<div>Group 2: <span id="g2"></span></div>
<div>Group 3: <span id="g3"></span></div>
```

Comment: Wow. This super ES6 solution, but not work in old browsers :(

Comment: Easy to adjust to ES5. You want ES5?

Comment: Connexo please help, why "undefined" value in my object? pls see https://jsfiddle.net/3vqr1ksy/5/

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you need to get param, then check needed value dependance of your param, check this example:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = "param=1&cb[gr1]=vl1-vl3&cb[gr2]=vl1&cb[gr3]=vl1-vl2-vl3",//window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};

var paramNum = getUrlParameter('param');
var paramGr  = getUrlParameter('cb[gr' + paramNum + ']');
var paramGrSplit = paramGr.split('-');

var valueString = '';
for(var i = 0; i < paramGrSplit.length; i++){
    $("input[value=" + paramGrSplit[i] + "]").prop('checked', true);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3vqr1ksy/2/)

When you have like this issue you need to subtract issue to subs and then create code for each sub, this will help you to resolve issue like this in future.

Comment: No. No GET, no POST, no address location. I need change in realtime (onClick) local string variable sample: If i checked gr1 - vl1 then $my_var = "cb[gr1]=vl1". If uncheked then $my_var=""